# ImportError while importing python

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip, anaconda, importerror

I am facing error in importing matplotlib.
ImportError: cannot import name 'animation' from 'matplotlib'
I have removed and reinstalled the matplotlib using both conda and pip method but still this problem is bothering me.

Comment: Could you please post a code snipped?

Comment: Is it possible that your file or other file is named `matplotlib.py`? Post the full traceback you get, verbatim along with your code.

Comment: I have just used import matplotlib.pyplot as plt